# Exporting .pgn notation to TeX file

Tags: pdf, chess, xskak

I've 855 positions in .pgn, which notations I want to export to .tex file. How can I do this? Should I do all of them one by one? In ChessBase, I can export them as .pdf file, but I cannot copy codes to .tex file, which I prepare. Also, I need a numeration. I've also tried pgn2latex, but my latex software didn't compiled the output file.

Something like this (font doesn't matter, main is a format):

[image]
[image]

Or this, but without the separation line.

[image]

With regards, Ulvi Bajarani

Comment: can you show the input as a text file, not as an image?

Comment: The documentation of xskak has a section with comments about inputting from a file (but it is from 2014 or so, so things can have changed). On the whole you probably will have to write some preprocessor (and the pgn shouldn't contain to many variations and comments ...).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the pgn2latex suggested here: https://rybkaforum.net/cgi-bin/rybkaforum/topic_show.pl?tid=32208

Tell us how it turn out. The only catch is you have to run python.

Comment: I've tried, but it didn't compile the .pgn, due to $ signs

Comment: Can you do a simple MWE of what you want exactly? I wish to learn from your experience as well. As for solution, another alternative is to open your pgn in scid. Using scid, you can export all the games to LATEX. But I must warn you, SCID's latex output is a bit cumbersome. You will get 1 page for each position. On the positive side, they provide a latex position for each game. It all depends on what you want.

Comment: I've opened all .pgn in Notepad++, and substituded all signs and commands (White, Black, Event, $19) with replacement (\whitename, \blackname, \WBetter, ! etc.) I've merged events, deleting cities. It's too handy, of course, but understanding, you can substitute all commnads by one click, controlling them.

Comment: I've forgotten to write that pgn2latex cannot compile notation without FEN, showing that the move number is other that 1.

Comment: Your experiment is very interesting. What is your desired output? A worksheet? A game analysis? Do you just want to recreate the same output as chessbase? Can you put in a sample MWE to illustrate?

Comment: \newcommand\printanswernumber{\refstepcounter{answers}\theanswers}

.....

\printanswernumber
\chessevent{Baku Ch-men final, 2005.04.19 (2)}
\whitename{Mehdiev, Afgan}
\blackname{Bajarani, Ulvi}
\whiteelo{-}
\blackelo{-}
\makegametitle

\textbf{26. Ngxf7! Ne4} [26... Rxf7 27. cxb5\WBetter] \textbf{27. c5 Kh7 28. Qd3 Kg8 29. Re2\WBetter}

this is some part of my code, starting with

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{book}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{texmate}

Comment: @UlviBajarani xskak can handle `$` comments, but not texmate.

Comment: @UlviBajarani  - There's no starting FEN position in your code. From what I see are you trying to have a diagram and then asking for the solution such as "White to Move." From your code, it seems like you can edit it manually one by one. But for 850 positions, you need a macro to help you out.

Comment: @user92127 Yes, I need the notations for last pages, where I'm going to provide the answers of positions. Without the FEN, pgn2latex didn't compiled the notation automatically, so I needed to do them by hand. It wasn't difficult to replace .pgn codes to LaTeX codes.

Comment: @UlviBajarani - I am testing out this presentation. You mention you don't have room to fillout the answer. Here's a suggestion. We can collaborate to get to the answer. I just want to learn how latex can make chess learning easier.  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/497894/testing-on-notation

Comment: @user92127 I don't know how I can help, because I am beginner in LaTeX. I've checked your test; This can be used for study contests.

Comment: @UlviBajarani - Ok. I am a beginner too. I want to learn more about LaTex, specifically things that LaTex can do better than Chessbase / Scid. Like I you, I have been teaching myself. I thought it would be better if we can work on a project to share ideas on how to learn LaTex.

Comment: @user92127 Ok, if there is something, I will help.