# Combining texmate header and xskak notation

Tags: parsing, chess, xskak

I tried to alter the [PGN2LaTeX3](https://rybkaforum.net/mwf/rybkaattach/35/581035/pgn2latex3.zip) in that manner that it should create headers in [my book](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/497827/numbering-chess-games-and-adjusting-makeevent-text/497837#497837), however I failed to do it.

for example, some pgn2latex_out.tex result:

```
\newgame
\resetPgnTags
\def\Site{}
\def\Date{2016}
\def\Round{9.1}
\def\whitename{Bajarani, Ulvi}
\def\blackname{Musayev, Eldar}
\def\Result{\aDraw}
\def\WhiteElo{2486}
\def\BlackElo{2159}
\fenboard{rn1qkbnr/pb1p1ppp/1p2p3/8/3pP3/P1N2N2/1PP2PPP/R1BQKB1R w KQkq - 0 6}
\gameHeader

\begin{samepage}    \mainline[level=1]{ 6. Nxd4 d6 7. Bd3 Nf6 8. O-O Be7 9. f4 Nbd7 10. Qe2 Qc7 11. g4 g6 12. Ndb5 Qb8 13. g5 Nh5 14. f5 O-O 15. fxe6 fxe6 16. Be3 Ng7 17. Nd4 Ne5 18. Bb5 Rxf1+ 19. Rxf1 Qd8 20. h4 a6 21. Ba4 b5 22. Bb3 Qd7 23. Nf3 Rf8 24. Nxe5 Rxf1+ 25. Qxf1 dxe5 26. Qd3 Qc8 27. Kf2 } \rdraw\end{samepage}

\newgame
\resetPgnTags
\def\Event{WYCC U18 Open Classic}
\def\Site{Al-Ain}
\def\Date{2013}
\def\Round{3.6}
\def\whitename{Draskovic, Luka}
\def\blackname{Bajarani, Ulvi}
\def\Result{\blackWins}
\def\WhiteElo{2282}
\def\BlackElo{2500}
\gameHeader

\mainline[level=1]{1. e4 e6 }

\variation[level=2]{1... c5 2. Nf3 d6 3. d4 cxd4 4. Nxd4 Nf6 5. Nc3 a6 6. Be3 e5 7. Nb3 Be6 8. f3 h5 9. Qd2 Nbd7 10. O-O-O Rc8 11. Kb1 b5 12. a3 Be7}

\mainline[level=1]{ 2. d4 d5 3. Nd2 }

\variation[level=2]{ 3. e5 c5 4. Qg4 cxd4}

\mainline[level=1]{ 3... Be7 4. e5 c5 5. Qg4 Kf8 }

\variation[level=2]{5... g6 6. dxc5 Nc6 7. Bb5 Bxc5 }\\(    \variation[level=3]{7... Qa5 8. Bxc6+ } (    \variation[level=4]{8. a4 Nh6 9. Qh3 Nf5 10. Ngf3 O-O 11. O-O Qc7 12. Bxc6 bxc6 13. Nb3 Ba6 14. Re1 h5 15. Bd2 Rab8 16. Ba5 Qb7 17. Bc3}) 
\variation[level=3]{ 8... bxc6})\\
\variation[level=2]{ 8. Nb3 Bf8 9. Nf3 Bg7 10. O-O}

\mainline[level=1]{ 6. dxc5 }

\variation[level=2]{\xskakcomment{\textbf{a)} } 6. Ndf3}

\variation[level=2]{\xskakcomment{\textbf{b)} } 6. Ngf3}

\mainline[level=1]{ 6... Nc6 }

\variation[level=2]{6... h5 7. Qg3 h4 8. Qf4 }\\(    \variation[level=3]{8. Qe3 Nd7 $11})\\
\variation[level=2]{ 8... Nc6 9. Ndf3 Bxc5 10. Nh3 Bb6 11. Bd3 $14}

\mainline[level=1]{ 7. Ngf3 }

\variation[level=2]{\xskakcomment{\textbf{a)} } 7. Qg3 $5 h5 8. Nb3 $5 h4 9. Qe3 h3 $3 }\\(    \variation[level=3]{9... Qc7 10. f4 Nh6 $1 11. Bd2 $1 } (    \variation[level=4]{11. Bd3 Nb4 12. Bd2 Nxd3+ 13. cxd3 Nf5 14. Qf2 $36 b6 15. Nf3 Ba6 $15}) 
\variation[level=3]{ 11... b6 12. cxb6 axb6 13. Bb5 Ba6 $11 14. Bxa6 } (    \variation[level=4]{14. a4 \xskakcomment{ Perexod}}     \variation[level=4]{ 14... Nb4 $15}) 
\variation[level=3]{ 14... Rxa6 $14 15. Qd3 Ra4 16. Ne2 $14})\\
\variation[level=2]{ 10. Nxh3 }\\(    \variation[level=3]{10. g4 b6 11. cxb6 d4 12. Qf4 axb6 13. Nf3 g5 14. Qg3 $11 } (    \variation[level=4]{14. Qe4 Bb7 $15}) 
\variation[level=3]{ 14... Qd5 $13})\\
\variation[level=2]{ 10... Nh6 11. Qc3 Nf5 $13 12. Bd3 }\\(    \variation[level=3]{12. Bf4 g5 13. Be3 } (    \variation[level=4]{13. Bg3 a5 14. a4 $1 b6 15. Bb5 Bb7 16. O-O Rc8 17. Rfd1 Nb4 18. Qf3 bxc5 19. c3 Nc6 20. Nd2 Qb6 $13}) 
\variation[level=3]{ 13... a5 14. Nd4 Ncxd4 15. Bxd4 $11 Bd7 $44 16. Bd3 Nxd4 17. Qxd4 Qc7 18. Qe3})\\
\variation[level=2]{ 12... d4 13. Qd2 $11 Rxh3 14. gxh3 Qd5 15. Rg1 Nxe5 16. Qf4 Nf3+ 17. Kf1 Nxg1 18. Kxg1 Nh4 19. Be4 Qh5 20. Qg4 Qe5 $11}

\variation[level=2]{\xskakcomment{\textbf{b)} } 7. Ndf3 $5 f6 }\\(    \variation[level=3]{7... h5 8. Qf4 Nh6 9. b4 g5 10. Nxg5 Nxe5 11. N5f3 $16})\\
\variation[level=2]{ 8. Qf4 }\par
{\addtolength{\leftskip}{1mm}    \variation[level=3]{\xskakcomment{\textbf{b1)} } 8. Nd4 fxe5 $11 9. Nxc6 bxc6 10. Nf3 Nf6 $15}\par} 
{\addtolength{\leftskip}{1mm}    \variation[level=3]{\xskakcomment{\textbf{b2)} } 8. Qg3 $5 Bxc5 $15 9. Bd3 Qc7 $1 }\par
    {\addtolength{\leftskip}{1mm}    \variation[level=4]{\xskakcomment{\textbf{b21)} } 9... fxe5 10. Nxe5 Nxe5 $44 11. Qxe5 Nf6 12. Bg5 Bd6 13. Qe3 Qb6 } (    \variation[level=5]{13... e5 $13 14. O-O-O $14}) 
\variation[level=4]{ 14. Qxb6 axb6 15. a3 Kf7 16. Be3 $14 e5 17. Bxb6 Nd7 18. Be3 Nc5 $44}\par} 
    {\addtolength{\leftskip}{1mm}    \variation[level=4]{\xskakcomment{\textbf{b22)} } 9... h5 10. exf6 } (    \variation[level=5]{10. Nh3 Nge7 11. exf6 gxf6 12. Nf4 e5 13. Ng6+ $14 \xskakcomment{ S shansamy na nicyu}}     \variation[level=5]{ 13... Nxg6 14. Qxg6 e4 15. Bh6+ Rxh6 16. Qxh6+ Kg8 17. O-O exd3 $11}) 
\variation[level=4]{ 10... Nxf6 11. Ne2 $14}\par} 
\variation[level=3]{ 10. Bf4 g5 11. Bd2 fxe5 12. Bb5 $1 } (    \variation[level=4]{12. Nxg5 h6 13. N5h3 Bd6 $15}) 
\variation[level=3]{ 12... Bd6 13. Qxg5 h6 14. Qe3 $1 Nge7 $15}\par} 
{\addtolength{\leftskip}{1mm}    \variation[level=3]{\xskakcomment{\textbf{b3)} } 8. Bf4 $6 h5 $1 9. Qg6 $44 } (    \variation[level=4]{9. Qg3 h4 10. Qg6 Bxc5 11. O-O-O Nge7 12. Qg4 Bd7 $5 } (    \variation[level=5]{12... Bxf2 $1 $14 \xskakcomment{ Stockfish 6 64 POPCNT: 2)}}     \variation[level=5]{ 13. Kb1 Qe8 14. Bd2 Bb6 15. Bc3 f5 16. Qg5 Ng6 $15}) 
\variation[level=4]{ 13. Be2 $5 } (    \variation[level=5]{13. Kb1 Qe8 14. Bd3 $132 } (    \variation[level=6]{14. Be3 $14 Bxe3 $6 15. fxe3 } (    \variation[level=7]{15. exf6 gxf6 16. fxe3 e5 17. Qa4 Qg6 $15}) 
\variation[level=6]{ 15... f5 16. Qa4 $15 Nxe5 $15}) 
\variation[level=5]{ 14... Qh5 15. Qxh5 Rxh5 $15}) 
\variation[level=4]{ 13... Qb6 14. Kb1 f5 15. Qg5 Rh6 $15}) 
\variation[level=3]{ 9... Bxc5 10. c3 Nge7 11. Qc2 $14 Qc7 12. exf6 Qxf4 13. fxe7+ Nxe7 $15}\par} 
\variation[level=2]{ 8... Bxc5 $13 \xskakcomment{ Houdini 4 Pro x64: 1)}}     \variation[level=2]{ 9. a3 $5 }\par
{\addtolength{\leftskip}{1mm}    \variation[level=3]{\xskakcomment{\textbf{b1)} } \xskakcomment{ Houdini 4 Pro x64: 2)}}     \variation[level=3]{ 9. Be3 Bxe3 10. fxe3 Qa5+ } (    \variation[level=4]{10... g5 $5 11. Nxg5 Qa5+ } (    \variation[level=5]{11... Nxe5 12. O-O-O Qb6 13. Bd3 } (    \variation[level=6]{13. Kb1 Kg7 $11}) 
\variation[level=5]{ 13... Nxd3+ 14. Rxd3 $11 e5 15. Qf2 Kg7 16. N5f3 Ne7 17. Ne2 Rf8 $11}) 
\variation[level=4]{ 12. Kd1 $5 } (    \variation[level=5]{12. c3 Nxe5 13. N1f3 } (    \variation[level=6]{13. N5f3 Ng6 14. Qd6+ N8e7 15. Bd3 Kg7 16. Ne2 Rd8 17. Qg3 e5 18. Bxg6 Nxg6 $15}) 
\variation[level=5]{ 13... Qb6 14. Nxe5 Qxb2 15. Ngf7 Qxc3+ 16. Kf2 Qxa1 17. Rg1 } (    \variation[level=6]{17. Bd3 Qxh1 18. Nxh8 Qd1 19. Bxh7 Qd2+ 20. Kf3 $11 }) 
\variation[level=5]{ 17... Qb2+ 18. Be2 fxe5 19. Nxe5+ Ke7 20. Qf7+ } (    \variation[level=6]{20. Rc1 Nh6 {} } (    \variation[level=7]{ 20... Qxc1 $4 21. Qb4+ $18}) 
\variation[level=6]{ 21. Rc7+ $5 Ke8 22. Nf7 Rg8 23. Nxh6 $1 Rxg2+ 24. Kxg2 Qxe2+ $11}) 
\variation[level=5]{ 20... Kd6 21. Qf8+ Ne7 22. Qxh8 Qxe5 23. Qd8+ Bd7 24. Qxa8 Qf6+ 25. Bf3 Qb2+ $11}) 
\variation[level=4]{ 12... Qb6 } (    \variation[level=5]{12... Nxe5 $6 $132 13. N1f3 Qb6 14. Nxe5 Qxb2 15. Nd3 } (    \variation[level=6]{15. Qd4 Qxd4+ 16. exd4 fxe5 17. Be2 $14 } (    \variation[level=7]{17. dxe5 h6 18. Nf3 $14 Ne7 19. Rb1 Rg8 20. Rb4 $132 Nc6 21. Rh4 Kg7 22. Bd3 Bd7 $11}) 
\variation[level=6]{ 17... Ne7 18. dxe5 Nc6 19. Rf1+ Ke8 20. Bb5 Rg8 21. Nf7 Kd7 22. Rb1 a6 23. Bxc6+ $14 Kxc6 $5 24. g3 $14})     \variation[level=6]{15. Nc6 e5 $15}) ) 
\variation[level=4]{ 13. exf6 e5 14. Qf3 } (    \variation[level=5]{14. Qf2 Qxb2 15. Rc1 e4 $15}) 
\variation[level=4]{ 14... h6 } (    \variation[level=5]{14... Qd8 15. Qh5 Qxf6 $132 16. Bb5 $14}) 
\variation[level=4]{ 15. f7 $132 hxg5 16. fxg8=Q+ Kxg8 17. Qxd5+ } (    \variation[level=5]{17. Qf6 Qxe3 $11}) 
\variation[level=4]{ 17... Kg7 18. Qb3 Rd8+ 19. Ke1 Nb4 20. a3 Nd3+ 21. Bxd3 Qxb3 $11 22. cxb3 $5 Rxd3 23. b4 Rxe3+ 24. Kd2 Rb3 25. Kc2 Re3 $11}) 
\variation[level=3]{ 11. c3 Qb6 12. O-O-O g5 13. Nxg5 Nxe5 $132 14. N5h3 }\par
    {\addtolength{\leftskip}{1mm}    \variation[level=4]{\xskakcomment{\textbf{b11)} } 14. N5f3 Ng6 15. Qd4 Kg7 $132}\par} 
    {\addtolength{\leftskip}{1mm}    \variation[level=4]{\xskakcomment{\textbf{b12)} } 14. Kb1 Ng6 $11 15. Qf3 $2 Kg7 16. N5h3 N8e7 $19 17. Nf4 $6 Rf8 $5 $11}\par} 
\variation[level=3]{ 14... h5 } (    \variation[level=4]{14... Nf7 15. Qf2 e5 $5 16. Rxd5 Ngh6 $11 17. e4 Ng4 18. Qxb6 axb6 $44 19. a3 $2 Ne3 20. Rd3 Nxf1 21. Ne2 Bg4 $15}) 
\variation[level=3]{ 15. e4 dxe4 16. Qxe4 Ng4 17. Nf3 Ne7 18. Bd3 e5 19. Rhe1 Bf5 20. Qe2 Rd8 21. Bxf5 Rxd1+ 22. Rxd1 Nxf5 23. Qc4 Kg7 24. Rd7+ Kh6 25. Qf7 Qe3+ 26. Kb1 Qe2 27. a4 Qe4+ 28. Ka2 Qxa4+ 29. Kb1 {} Qe4+ 30. Ka2 Qa4+ 31. Kb1 {}}\par} 
{\addtolength{\leftskip}{1mm}    \variation[level=3]{\xskakcomment{\textbf{b2)} } \xskakcomment{ Houdini 4 Pro x64: 3) }}     \variation[level=3]{ 9. Bd2 Qb6 } (    \variation[level=4]{9... g5 10. Qa4 $14 } (    \variation[level=5]{10. Qg3 h5 11. exf6 g4 $1 12. Bc3 d4 13. O-O-O Bd6 14. Rxd4 $5 Bxg3 15. Rxd8+ Nxd8 16. hxg3 gxf3 17. Nxf3 Rh6 $15}) 
\variation[level=4]{ 10... a6 } (    \variation[level=5]{10... fxe5 11. O-O-O e4 12. Nxg5 Qe7 } (    \variation[level=6]{12... Qc7 13. Nxe4 dxe4 14. Qxe4 $13}) 
\variation[level=5]{ 13. Bb5 Nf6 14. Bxc6 $14 bxc6 15. f3 } (    \variation[level=6]{15. Qxc6 Rb8 $15}) 
\variation[level=5]{ 15... h6 16. fxe4 hxg5 17. Rf1 $14 Kg7 $5 18. Bxg5 Rf8 19. Nh3 Qe8 20. Bxf6+ Rxf6 $1 21. Rxf6 Kxf6 22. exd5 exd5 $14 23. Qf4+ Kg7 24. Qg3+ Kh7 25. Qh4+ Kg8 $11}) 
\variation[level=4]{ 11. exf6 } (    \variation[level=5]{11. O-O-O $132 fxe5 12. Bxg5 } (    \variation[level=6]{12. Bb5 $11 Na7 13. Be2 Nc6 14. Bb5 $11}) 
\variation[level=5]{ 12... Qc7 13. Be3 Be7 $15}) 
\variation[level=4]{ 11... h6 $1 12. h4 g4 13. Qxg4 Qxf6 14. O-O-O e5 15. Qh5 Be6 16. Ne1 $1 $14 Bf7 17. Qg4 Be6 $11}) 
\variation[level=3]{ 10. O-O-O g5 11. Qa4 fxe5 } (    \variation[level=4]{11... Bd7 12. Bb5 h6 $11 13. Ne2 a6 14. Bxc6 Bxc6 $11 15. Qb3 Qxb3 $1 $11 16. axb3 f5 17. Nfd4 Kf7 18. h4 g4 19. Be3 Bb5 $36 20. Nf4 $6 Bxd4 $5 21. Bxd4 Ne7 $11}) 
\variation[level=3]{ 12. h4 g4 13. Qxg4 Nf6 14. Qg5 Kf7 15. Ne2 Bd6 $11 16. Qh6 {} Bf8 17. Qg5 Bd6 18. Qh6 {}}\par} 
{\addtolength{\leftskip}{1mm}    \variation[level=3]{\xskakcomment{\textbf{b3)} } 9. c3 $6 $11 Bb6 $5 } (    \variation[level=4]{9... Bd7 10. Bd3 Bb6 11. Be3 g5 12. Qg3 Bxe3 13. fxe3 Qb6 $14 14. exf6 Qxe3+ 15. Ne2 Nxf6 16. Nxg5 Qxg3+ 17. Nxg3 Ne5 $11}) 
\variation[level=3]{ 10. Bb5 Bc7 11. Bxc6 bxc6 12. Qe3 Ne7 13. exf6 gxf6 14. Qh6+ Kf7 $15}\par} 
\variation[level=2]{ 9... Qa5+ }\par
{\addtolength{\leftskip}{1mm}    \variation[level=3]{\xskakcomment{\textbf{b1)} } 9... Qb6 $1 10. Nh3 Nxe5 11. Nxe5 $11 Bd6 $1 12. Nc4 dxc4 13. Qxc4 $15 e5 $15}\par} 
{\addtolength{\leftskip}{1mm}    \variation[level=3]{\xskakcomment{\textbf{b2)} } 9... g5 10. Qg3 h5 11. exf6 g4 12. Bg5 Bd6 13. Nh4 Bxg3 14. Ng6+ Kf7 15. Nxh8+ Kf8 $11}\par} 
\variation[level=2]{ 10. Bd2 Qb6 11. O-O-O g5 12. Qa4 fxe5 $14 13. h4 $36 Nge7 14. Qg4 e4 15. Qxg5 Rg8 16. Qh6+ Rg7 17. Bc3 Nf5 18. Bxg7+ Kg8 19. Qf4 Bxf2 20. Bd4 Ncxd4 21. Qg5+ Kh8 {} 22. Qf6+ Kg8 23. Qg5+ Kh8 {}}

\variation[level=2]{\xskakcomment{\textbf{c)} } 7. Qe2 b6 $5 }\\(    \variation[level=3]{7... Bxc5 8. Nb3 Bb6 9. Nf3 Nge7 10. Be3 } (    \variation[level=4]{10. Bd2}) 
\variation[level=3]{ 10... Ng6 11. O-O-O Bc7 12. Kb1 Ngxe5 13. Nxe5 {} Bxe5 14. f4 Bd6 15. g3 $36})\\
\variation[level=2]{ 8. cxb6 axb6 $44 9. Ngf3 }\\(    \variation[level=3]{9. f4 Nh6 10. c3 Nf5 11. Qf2 Bc5 $17})\\
\variation[level=2]{ 9... Qc7 $44}

\variation[level=2]{\xskakcomment{\textbf{d)} } 7. Qf4 $6 g5 8. Qe3 Nh6 \xskakcomment{ Stockfish 6 64 POPCNT: 4)}}     \variation[level=2]{ 9. Qc3 Nf5 $15}

\mainline[level=1]{ 7... h5 8. Qa4 }

\variation[level=2]{\xskakcomment{\textbf{a)} } 8. Qg3 h4 }\\(    \variation[level=3]{8... Qc7 $6 9. h4 a5 } (    \variation[level=4]{9... Nh6 $11 10. Nb3 Nf5 11. Qf4 $14}) 
\variation[level=3]{ 10. a4 Bxc5 11. Nb3 b6 $11 12. Bb5 $14})\\
\variation[level=2]{ 9. Qf4 g5 $1 10. Qe3 $1 }\\(    \variation[level=3]{10. Qa4 h3 11. Nb3 } (    \variation[level=4]{ 11. gxh3 Qc7 12. h4 Nxe5 13. hxg5 Bxc5 14. Nxe5 Qxe5+ 15. Be2 Rxh2 16. Rf1 Rh3 17. Qg4 $1 } (    \variation[level=5]{17. Nb3 Bd6 $13}) 
\variation[level=4]{ 17... Qh8 $13}) 
\variation[level=3]{ 11... hxg2 12. Bxg2 Qc7 $5 } (    \variation[level=4]{12... Bd7 13. Qg4 Nh6 14. Qh5 f6 15. exf6 Bxf6 16. Nxg5 Qe7 17. f4 } (    \variation[level=5]{17. h4 $5 Nf5 18. Qe2 Nxh4 19. f4 Re8 20. c3 Nxg2+ 21. Qxg2 Rxh1+ 22. Qxh1 e5 $13}) 
\variation[level=4]{ 17... e5 18. Qe2 } (    \variation[level=5]{18. O-O Ng4 $19}) 
\variation[level=4]{ 18... Bg4 $11 19. Bf3 Bxf3 20. Nxf3 Nf5 21. fxe5 \xskakcomment{ Perexod }}     \variation[level=4]{ 21... Ng3 22. Qg2 Nxh1 23. Be3 Nxe5 24. O-O-O Nc4 25. Bd4 Ne3 \xskakcomment{ Perexod}}     \variation[level=4]{ 26. Bxe3 Qxe3+ 27. Kb1 Nf2 28. Re1 Qf4 29. Qxf2 Bh4 $11 30. Qe3 Qxe3 31. Rxe3 $11}) 
\variation[level=3]{ 13. h4 Nxe5 14. hxg5 Nxf3+ 15. Bxf3 Rxh1+ 16. Bxh1 Qh2 17. Bf3 e5 18. Bxd5 Qg1+ 19. Ke2 Bg4+ 20. Bf3 $5 Bxf3+ 21. Kxf3 $11 e4+ 22. Ke2 Qg4+ $11})\\
\variation[level=2]{ 10... b6 $5 11. cxb6 Nh6 $13 12. h3 }\\(    \variation[level=3]{12. bxa7 h3 13. gxh3 } (    \variation[level=4]{13. g3 d4 14. Qe4 Bb7 $15}) 
\variation[level=3]{ 13... Nf5 14. Qe2 Rxa7 $13})\\
\variation[level=2]{ 12... axb6 $5 13. Bb5 Nb4 14. Qb3 g4 15. hxg4 Nxg4 16. Nd4 Nxe5 17. f4 Nc4 $15}

\variation[level=2]{\xskakcomment{\textbf{b)} } 8. Qf4 g5 9. Qe3 d4 10. Qe2 g4 11. Ng1 $11 Qd5 12. h3 Nxe5 13. hxg4 Nxg4 14. Nb3 a5 15. a4 e5 $15}

\mainline[level=1]{ 8... Qc7 9. Qf4 f6 }

\variation[level=2]{\xskakcomment{\textbf{a)} } 9... Nh6 $5 10. Bb5 }\par
{\addtolength{\leftskip}{1mm}    \variation[level=3]{\xskakcomment{\textbf{a1)} } 10. h3 f6 11. Nb3 Nxe5 12. Nxe5 Qxe5+ 13. Qxe5 fxe5 14. Bb5 Nf5 $132}\par} 
{\addtolength{\leftskip}{1mm}    \variation[level=3]{\xskakcomment{\textbf{a2)} } 10. Nb3 Ng4 11. Bd2 Ngxe5 12. O-O-O Bd7 $132}\par} 
\variation[level=2]{ 10... Bxc5 }\par
{\addtolength{\leftskip}{1mm}    \variation[level=3]{\xskakcomment{\textbf{a1)} } 10... Nf5 11. Nb3 a5 } (    \variation[level=4]{11... g5 12. Nxg5 Bxg5 13. Qxg5 Qxe5+ 14. Be2 Rg8 15. Qf4 Qh8}) 
\variation[level=3]{ 12. a4 } (    \variation[level=4]{\xskakcomment{Stockfish 6 64 POPCNT: 2)}}     \variation[level=4]{ 12. Bxc6 bxc6 13. Qa4 Ba6 14. Bd2 Bb5 15. Bxa5 Bxa4 16. Bxc7 Bxb3 17. cxb3 Bxc5 18. Ke2 Ke8 19. Rhc1 Be7 20. Bb6 Kd7 21. Bc5 Bxc5 22. Rxc5 Rhb8 23. Rcc1 c5 24. h3 Kc6 25. Rc3 c4 26. Rc2 Rxb3 27. axb3 Rxa1 28. bxc4 Ra2 29. cxd5+ Kxd5 30. g4 Nd4+ 31. Nxd4 Kxd4 {}}) 
\variation[level=3]{ 12... g5 13. Nxg5 Bxg5 14. Qxg5 Qxe5+ 15. Be2 } (    \variation[level=4]{15. Be3 $6 Rg8 } (    \variation[level=5]{15... Qxb2 16. Bxc6 bxc6 17. O-O Rg8 18. Qd8+ Kg7 19. Qc7 $1 $14}) 
\variation[level=4]{ 16. Qxh5 Qxb2 $15}) 
\variation[level=3]{ 15... f6 $1 } (    \variation[level=4]{15... Rg8 16. Qxh5 } (    \variation[level=5]{16. Qf4 Qxf4 17. Bxf4 e5 18. Bd2 Nfd4 19. Nxd4 Nxd4 20. Bd1 Bf5 21. c3 Ne6 } (    \variation[level=6]{21... Nc2+ 22. Bxc2 Bxc2 23. O-O $14}) 
\variation[level=5]{ 22. O-O Bh3 23. Bf3 e4 24. Kh1 exf3 25. gxh3 Nxc5 26. Be3 Ne4 $132}) 
\variation[level=4]{ 16... Rxg2 17. c3 $14}) 
\variation[level=3]{ 16. Qf4 } (    \variation[level=4]{16. Qd2 Nfd4 17. Nxd4 Nxd4 18. f4 Qe4 19. Kf1 Nxe2 20. Qxe2 Qxe2+ 21. Kxe2 Kf7 $44}) 
\variation[level=3]{ 16... Qxf4 17. Bxf4 e5 18. Be3 } (    \variation[level=4]{18. Bd2 Nfd4 19. Nxd4 Nxd4 20. Bd1 Bf5 21. c3 Ne6 22. Bb3 Nxc5 23. Bxd5 Nd3+ 24. Ke2 Nxb2 25. Rhb1 Bd3+ 26. Ke3 Rd8 27. Rxb2 Rxd5 28. Rxb7 Rg8 29. g3 Rg7 $14 \xskakcomment{ S shansamy na nicyu}}) 
\variation[level=3]{ 18... Be6 19. O-O Rg8 $44}\par} 
{\addtolength{\leftskip}{1mm}    \variation[level=3]{\xskakcomment{\textbf{a2)} } \xskakcomment{ Stockfish 6 64 POPCNT: 4)}}     \variation[level=3]{ 10... a5 11. O-O Nf5 12. c3 g5 13. Qa4 Bd7 14. Nb3 Nxe5 15. Nxe5 Bxb5 16. Qxb5 Qxe5 17. Qxb7 Kg7 18. Bd2 Rhb8 19. Qd7 Rd8 20. Qa4 Qe2 21. c6 Qc4 22. Qxc4 dxc4 23. Nd4 Nxd4 24. cxd4 Rdc8 {} }\par} 
{\addtolength{\leftskip}{1mm}    \variation[level=3]{\xskakcomment{\textbf{a3)} } 10... g5 $2 11. Nxg5 Nf5 12. Ngf3 } (    \variation[level=4]{12. Bxc6 Bxg5 13. Qxg5 Rg8 14. Qxh5 Qxe5+ 15. Qe2 Qxe2+ 16. Kxe2 bxc6 17. g3 Nd4+ 18. Kd1 e5 19. Nb3 Bg4+ 20. Kd2 Ne6 $44 21. Na5 Nxc5 22. b3 Ne4+ 23. Ke3 Ng5 24. Ba3+ Kg7 25. Nxc6 Rac8 26. Nxe5 Rge8 27. f4 Rxc2 $44}) 
\variation[level=3]{ 12... Rg8 13. h3 Rxg2 14. Kf1 Rg6 15. Nb3 $16}\par} 
\variation[level=2]{ 11. Nb3 Qb6 $1 }\par
{\addtolength{\leftskip}{1mm}    \variation[level=3]{\xskakcomment{\textbf{a1)} } 11... Bb6 12. O-O Ng4 13. Bxc6 bxc6 14. h3 Nh6 15. Be3 $14}\par} 
{\addtolength{\leftskip}{1mm}    \variation[level=3]{\xskakcomment{\textbf{a2)} } 11... Be7 12. O-O } (    \variation[level=4]{12. Bd2 g5 13. Nxg5 Qxe5+ 14. Qxe5 Nxe5 15. Bc3 f6 16. Nh3 Ng6 $11 17. f4 Nh4 18. g3 Nf3+ 19. Ke2 d4 $15}) 
\variation[level=3]{ 12... g5 } (    \variation[level=4]{12... a6 13. Bxc6 bxc6 14. c4 c5 15. cxd5 exd5 16. Be3 d4 17. Bd2 a5 18. Rfc1 Qb6 19. Qe4 Bb7 20. Qc2 Bxf3 21. gxf3 Kg8 22. Qe4 $14}) 
\variation[level=3]{ 13. Nxg5 Qxe5 14. Nf3 Qxf4 15. Bxf4 Nf5 16. Bd3 Bd6 17. Bxd6+ Nxd6 18. Rfe1 Kg7 $11}\par} 
\variation[level=2]{ 12. Nxc5 }\\(    \variation[level=3]{12. Bd3 $2 Bxf2+ 13. Ke2 Nf5 $15})\\
\variation[level=2]{ 12... Qxb5 13. Nb3 }\\(    \variation[level=3]{13. Nd3 Qc4 14. Qxc4 dxc4 15. Bxh6 cxd3 16. Bd2 dxc2 17. Rc1 Ke7 18. Rxc2 Rd8 19. Ke2 Rd5 $11})\\
\variation[level=2]{ 13... Nf5 14. Be3 b6 15. O-O-O Qc4 16. Rhe1 Qxf4 17. Bxf4 f6 18. Bd2 Kf7 19. Bc3 Ba6 20. Nbd4 Ncxd4 21. Nxd4 Nxd4 22. Bxd4 Rhg8 23. a4 f5 24. Kd2 h4 25. Ra1 g5 26. a5 b5 $11}

\variation[level=2]{\xskakcomment{\textbf{b)} } \xskakcomment{ Stockfish 6 64 POPCNT: 2)}}     \variation[level=2]{ 9... Bxc5 10. Nb3 Be7 11. Bd2 Nh6 12. Be2 a5 13. c4 Ng4 }\\(    \variation[level=3]{\xskakcomment{Houdini 4 Pro x64:}}     \variation[level=3]{ 13... dxc4 14. Qxc4 Ng4 15. O-O Ngxe5 16. Nxe5 Qxe5 17. Rfd1 a4 18. Bc3 Qf5 19. Nd4 Qd5 20. Qd3 Nxd4 21. Qxd4 Qxd4 22. Bxd4 Bd7 23. Bxg7+ Kxg7 24. Rxd7 Bf6 25. Rad1 Rac8 26. Bb5 Bxb2 27. Bxa4 b6 28. Rb1 Bf6 29. Rxb6 Rhd8 30. Rbd6 Rxd7 31. Rxd7 Rd8 32. Rxd8 Bxd8 33. g3 Kf6 34. Kg2 {}})\\
\variation[level=2]{ 14. cxd5 exd5 \xskakcomment{ Houdini 4 Pro x64: 1)}}     \variation[level=2]{ 15. Rc1 $1 }\\(    \variation[level=3]{\xskakcomment{Houdini 4 Pro x64: 2)}}     \variation[level=3]{ 15. Bc3 Bb4 16. O-O Bxc3 17. bxc3 Rh6 18. Rad1 Be6 19. Nbd4 Ncxe5 20. Nxe5 Nxe5 21. Nxe6+ Rxe6 22. Rxd5 g6 23. Rb1 Rc8 24. Bf1 b6 25. h3 Kg7 26. Ba6 Rd8 27. c4 f6 28. a4 Rxd5 29. cxd5 Rd6 30. Rd1 Qc5 31. Qd2 Qb4 {}})\\
\variation[level=2]{ 15... Ngxe5 16. Nxe5 Bd6 17. Qxf7+ Qxf7 18. Nxf7 Kxf7 19. O-O Bg4 20. Bd3 Rhc8 21. Nc5 Bxc5 22. Rxc5 Ne5 23. Rxc8 Rxc8 24. Bb1 d4 25. f3 Be6 26. b3 Kf6 27. Be4 b6 28. g4 Bd7 29. g5+ Kf7 30. Kf2 d3 31. Ke3 Rc2 32. f4 Ng4+ 33. Kxd3 Rxa2 {}}

\mainline[level=1]{ 10. Nb3 }

\variation[level=2]{\xskakcomment{\textbf{a)} } 10. Bb5 Nxe5 11. Nxe5 Qxe5+ 12. Qxe5 fxe5 13. Nf3 Bf6 14. O-O Ke7 $13}

\variation[level=2]{\xskakcomment{\textbf{b)} } 10. b4 $1 Nh6 }\par
{\addtolength{\leftskip}{1mm}    \variation[level=3]{\xskakcomment{\textbf{b1)} } 10... Nxe5 11. Nxe5 Qxe5+ 12. Qxe5 fxe5 13. Nf3 Bf6 14. Bb2 e4 15. Ne5 Ne7 16. f3 $1 } (    \variation[level=4]{16. f4 $6 Rh7 $5 } (    \variation[level=5]{16... Kg8 $5 17. Bb5 } (    \variation[level=6]{17. Bd4 Ng6 18. O-O-O Bxe5 19. fxe5 Bd7 $132}) 
\variation[level=5]{ 17... Nf5 18. O-O-O Ne3 19. Rd2 a6 20. Ba4 a5 21. b5 Bxe5 22. Bxe5 Bd7 $132}) 
\variation[level=4]{ 17. a3 Nf5 18. Bb5 g5 $5 } (    \variation[level=5]{18... a5 19. O-O Kg8 20. Be8 Ne3 21. Rf2 axb4 22. axb4 Rxa1+ 23. Bxa1 Ng4 24. Rf1 Ne3 $11}) 
\variation[level=4]{ 19. fxg5 Bxg5 20. O-O a6 21. Ba4 a5 $132}) 
\variation[level=3]{ 16... Rh6 $1 }\par
    {\addtolength{\leftskip}{1mm}    \variation[level=4]{\xskakcomment{\textbf{b11)} } 16... exf3 17. gxf3 Rh6 18. Rg1 Nc6 19. f4 Nxb4 20. Kd2 $36}\par} 
    {\addtolength{\leftskip}{1mm}    \variation[level=4]{\xskakcomment{\textbf{b12)} } 16... h4 $6 17. O-O-O $5 } (    \variation[level=5]{17. Be2 $5 Rh5 18. f4 Rf5 19. O-O } (    \variation[level=6]{19. Rf1 $2 Nc6 20. Bg4 Nxe5 21. fxe5 } (    \variation[level=7]{21. Bxf5 $2 Nd3+ 22. cxd3 Bxb2 $19}) 
\variation[level=6]{ 21... Rxf1+ 22. Kxf1 Bg5 $11}) 
\variation[level=5]{ 19... g5 20. g3 $1 } (    \variation[level=6]{20. fxg5 Bxg5 21. c4 a5 $1 22. b5 Be3+ 23. Kh1 Bxc5 24. Rad1 $5 } (    \variation[level=7]{24. Bg4 d4 25. Bxf5 exf5 $44}) 
\variation[level=6]{ 24... a4 25. a3 b6 26. Bg4 Rxf1+ 27. Rxf1+ Ke8 28. Bh5+ Kd8 29. Rf7 d4 30. Nc6+ Nxc6 31. bxc6 e5 32. c7+ Ke8 33. Kg1 Be7 34. Rf5+ Kd7 35. Rxe5 Bc5 36. Rxe4 Kxc7 37. Rxh4 Be6 $11}) 
\variation[level=5]{ 20... hxg3 } (    \variation[level=6]{20... gxf4 21. gxf4 Nc6 22. Bg4 Bxe5 23. fxe5 Nxb4 24. Bxf5 exf5 25. Rf4 h3 26. Kf2 $16}) 
\variation[level=5]{ 21. hxg3 gxf4 22. gxf4 $14}) 
\variation[level=4]{ 17... Rh5 } (    \variation[level=5]{17... b6 18. fxe4 Rh5 } (    \variation[level=6]{18... bxc5 19. exd5 exd5 20. Bd3 cxb4 21. Rde1 $14}) 
\variation[level=5]{ 19. Nd3 dxe4 20. Bxf6 gxf6 21. Nf4 Re5 22. Rd8+ Kf7 23. Bc4 Bb7 24. Rd7 Bd5 25. Bxd5 exd5 26. c6 $14}) 
\variation[level=4]{ 18. f4 Rh6 } (    \variation[level=5]{18... Rf5 19. g3 Nc6 20. g4 } (    \variation[level=6]{20. Nxc6 bxc6 21. Bxf6 Rxf6 $132}) 
\variation[level=5]{ 20... Rxf4 21. Ng6+ Kf7 22. Nxf4 Bg5 23. Kb1 Bxf4 24. a3 $14}) 
\variation[level=4]{ 19. Bb5 $14}\par} 
\variation[level=3]{ 17. O-O-O } (    \variation[level=4]{17. Rb1 exf3 18. gxf3 } (    \variation[level=5]{18. Nxf3 e5 $1 $11}) 
\variation[level=4]{ 18... Ng6 $11}) 
\variation[level=3]{ 17... exf3 18. gxf3 } (    \variation[level=4]{18. Nxf3 b6 19. Bd3 Nc6 20. b5 Nb4 21. Bxf6 Nxd3+ 22. Rxd3 gxf6 23. c6 Rg6 24. c4 Rxg2 25. cxd5 exd5 26. Rxd5 Rxa2 $11}) 
\variation[level=3]{ 18... Ng6 } (    \variation[level=4]{18... Nc6 19. Nd3 a5 20. b5 } (    \variation[level=5]{20. Bxf6 Rxf6 21. b5 Nd4 22. a4 Nxf3 23. Be2 Ng5 24. Bxh5 Ne4 $11}) 
\variation[level=4]{ 20... Nd4 21. Nf4 Nxf3 22. Be2 $36}) 
\variation[level=3]{ 19. Nd3 $5 } (    \variation[level=4]{19. Nxg6+ Rxg6 20. Bd3 Rg2 21. Bxf6 } (    \variation[level=5]{21. Rdg1 Rxg1+ 22. Rxg1 e5 $1 } (    \variation[level=6]{22... Bd7 23. Bxf6 gxf6 \xskakcomment{ Perexod}}) 
\variation[level=5]{ 23. Re1 d4 24. Be4 Rb8 25. c3 Bd7 26. cxd4 } (    \variation[level=6]{26. Kc2 Ba4+ 27. Kd3 dxc3 28. Kxc3 Rd8 $1 29. Re3 b6 30. Rd3 Rxd3+ 31. Kxd3 Bb5+ $11}) 
\variation[level=5]{ 26... exd4 27. Rd1 Ba4 28. Bc2 Bc6 29. Bxd4 Bxf3 30. Bxf6 Bxd1 31. Be5 Bxc2 32. Bxb8 Ba4 33. Bxa7 Kf7 $11}) 
\variation[level=4]{ 21... gxf6 22. Rdg1 Rxg1+ 23. Rxg1 Bd7 \xskakcomment{ Perexod}}     \variation[level=4]{ 24. Rg6 } (    \variation[level=5]{24. Kb2 Kf7 25. f4 } (    \variation[level=6]{25. c4 dxc4 26. Bxc4 b6 27. Kc3 bxc5 28. bxc5 Rc8 29. Kd4 Rd8 30. Rb1 Bc6+ 31. Ke3 f5 32. f4 Kf6 33. Bb3 e5 34. Rd1 Rxd1 35. Bxd1 h4 $11}) 
\variation[level=5]{ 25... b6 26. Bg6+ Ke7 27. Bxh5 Rh8 28. Rg7+ Kd8 29. Bf7 bxc5 30. bxc5 Rxh2 31. c6 Bxc6 32. Bxe6 a5 33. Kc3 Rf2 34. f5 Ba4 $11}) 
\variation[level=4]{ 24... f5 25. f4 a5 26. a3 axb4 27. axb4 Ra4 28. c3 d4 29. Kb2 dxc3+ 30. Kxc3 Ra3+ 31. Kd4 Rb3 32. Rh6 } (    \variation[level=5]{32. Kc4 Rb2 33. Rh6 Rxh2 34. Rh7 Bc6 35. b5 Bd5+ 36. Kd4 Rd2 $11}) 
\variation[level=4]{ 32... Rxb4+ 33. Ke5 Kg7 34. Rxh5 b6 35. cxb6 Rxb6 36. Rg5+ Kf7 37. Be2 Rb2 $1 38. Rg2 } (    \variation[level=5]{38. Bh5+ Kf8 $11}) 
\variation[level=4]{ 38... Kf8 39. Bf3 Rb4 40. Bh5 Re4+ 41. Kf6 Be8 42. Bxe8 Kxe8 $11}) 
\variation[level=3]{ 19... Bd7 20. Bh3 a5 } (    \variation[level=4]{20... Nh4 21. f4 a5 22. Rhe1 axb4 23. Nxb4 Bxb2+ 24. Kxb2 Ra5 \xskakcomment{ Perexod}}) 
\variation[level=3]{ 21. Rhe1 Nh4 22. f4 Bxb2+ } (    \variation[level=4]{22... axb4 23. Nxb4 Bxb2+ 24. Kxb2 Ra5 \xskakcomment{ Perexod}}) 
\variation[level=3]{ 23. Kxb2 axb4 24. Nxb4 Ra5 \xskakcomment{ Perexod}}     \variation[level=3]{ 25. Nxd5 } (    \variation[level=4]{25. c4 Ba4 26. Rc1 Nf3 27. Rxe6 Rxe6 28. Bxe6 dxc4 29. Rc3 Nd4 30. Bxc4 Rxc5 31. Bf1 Ra5 32. Rc8+ Be8 $11}) 
\variation[level=3]{ 25... exd5 26. Bxd7 Rxc5 27. Re5 Nf3 28. Re8+ Kf7 29. Re2 Rb6+ 30. Kc1 Nh4 31. Be8+ Kf6 32. Bxh5 Ra6 33. Kb2 Rb6+ 34. Ka1 g6 35. Bg4 Rb4 36. Rb1 Rxf4 37. Rb6+ Rc6 38. Rxc6+ bxc6 39. Bd7 Nf3 $5 40. Re6+ Kg7 $11}\par} 
{\addtolength{\leftskip}{1mm}    \variation[level=3]{\xskakcomment{\textbf{b2)} } 10... g5 11. Nxg5 Qxe5+ 12. Qxe5 fxe5 13. Ndf3 e4 14. Nh4 Kg7 15. Rb1 $14}\par} 
\variation[level=2]{ 11. Nb3 Nxe5 12. Nxe5 Qxe5+ 13. Qxe5 fxe5 14. Bb2 }\\(    \variation[level=3]{14. Be2 $5 Nf5 15. Bb2 a5 16. bxa5 $14 } (    \variation[level=4]{16. Nxa5 Nd4 17. Bd3 b6 $132}) )\\
\variation[level=2]{ 14... Bf6 15. c4 Nf5 16. Be2 $14}

\variation[level=2]{\xskakcomment{\textbf{c)} } 10. Be2 Nxe5 11. Nxe5 Qxe5 12. Qxe5 fxe5 13. b4 a5 14. Nf3 Bf6 15. Bb2 e4 16. Ne5 Bxe5 17. Bxe5 axb4 18. f3 Nf6 19. O-O Kf7 20. fxe4 dxe4 21. Bc4 Bd7 22. Rad1 Bc6 23. Rd6 Bd5 24. Bxd5 exd5 25. Bxf6 gxf6 26. Rfxf6+ Ke7 27. Rfe6+ Kf7 28. Rf6+ {}}

\mainline[level=1]{ 10... Nxe5 11. c4 Nh6 12. cxd5 exd5 13. Be2 Bg4 14. Nfd4 }

\variation[level=2]{14. O-O Nf5 }\\(    \variation[level=3]{14... g5 $4 15. Nxg5 $18})\\
\variation[level=2]{ 15. Nxe5 fxe5 16. Qd2 Bxe2 17. Qxe2 Bf6 18. Rd1 Ne7 $11}

\mainline[level=1]{ 14... Kf7 15. f3 Bd7 16. O-O Rac8 }

\variation[level=2]{16... Bxc5 17. Nxc5 Qxc5 18. Be3 g5 19. Qg3 Nc6 20. Rfd1 $11}

\mainline[level=1]{ 17. Qh4 Bxc5 18. Nxc5 Qxc5 19. Be3 Qe7 $13 20. Qf2 $2 Rce8 $2 }

\variation[level=2]{20... Nf5 $1 21. Nxf5 Bxf5 22. Rfe1 Rc2 $15}

\mainline[level=1]{ 21. Rfe1 g5 $2 }
 Niveliruya g4-g5 v nijnem variante

\variation[level=2]{21... Neg4 22. fxg4 Qxe3 23. Qxe3 Rxe3 24. g5 $1 Ng4 25. g6+ }\\(    \variation[level=3]{25. h3 Re4 26. g6+ Ke7 27. Bf3 Rxe1+ 28. Rxe1+ Ne5 29. Bxd5 Kd6 30. Be4 b6 $11})\\
\variation[level=2]{ 25... Kf8 }\\(    \variation[level=3]{ 25... Kxg6 26. h3 Rhe8 27. hxg4 hxg4 28. Rac1 R8e4 29. Rc3 $14})\\
\variation[level=2]{ 26. Rac1 Re4 27. Rc7 Ne5 28. Rd1 Rh6 29. Rxb7 Rxg6 30. Bxh5 Rg5 $11}

\mainline[level=1]{ 22. h3 $6 }

\variation[level=2]{22. Nb5 $5 Nf5 23. Bxa7 Bxb5 24. Bxb5 Ra8 25. Bc5 Qe6 26. a4 Rad8 27. Rac1 h4 28. h3 $16}

\mainline[level=1]{ 22... Neg4 23. hxg4 Qxe3 24. Qxe3 }

\variation[level=2]{24. gxh5 Nf5 25. Nxf5 Bxf5 26. g4 $5 Bd7 27. Qxe3 Rxe3 28. Kf2 Rhe8 29. Rad1 Kg7 30. Rxd5 Bc6 31. Rd2 Bxf3 32. Bb5 $1 Rxe1 33. Bxe8 Rxe8 $1 34. Rd7+ Kh6 35. Kxf3 Rf8 36. Ke4 }\\(    \variation[level=3]{36. Rxb7 f5 37. Rxa7 fxg4+ 38. Kxg4 Rf4+ 39. Kg3 Rg4+ 40. Kf3 Rf4+ 41. Kg2 } (    \variation[level=4]{41. Ke3 Rf8 $11}) 
\variation[level=3]{ 41... Kxh5 $11 \xskakcomment{ Lomonosov Table Draw}})\\
\variation[level=2]{ 36... Re8+ 37. Kf5 $2 Re5+ 38. Kxf6 Re4 $11}

\mainline[level=1]{ 24... Rxe3 25. gxh5 g4 26. Kf2 Rhe8 27. g3 $2 }

\variation[level=2]{27. Rac1 Kf8 }\\(    \variation[level=3]{27... g3+ $2 28. Kxg3 Nf5+ 29. Nxf5 Bxf5 30. Kf2 $18})\\
\variation[level=2]{ 28. fxg4 R3e4 29. Nf5 $11 Nxg4+ 30. Bxg4 Rxg4 31. Rxe8+ Bxe8 32. Kf3 Rg5 33. g4 Bd7 34. h6 Bxf5 35. gxf5 Rxf5+ 36. Ke3 Rh5 37. Rc8+ Kf7 38. Rc7+ Kg6 39. Rxb7 a5 40. Ra7 Kxh6 $11}

\mainline[level=1]{ 27... R3e5 28. Bb5 Bxb5 29. Nxb5 R8e6 $1 30. Nd4 $2 }

\variation[level=2]{30. Rac1 Rb6 31. Rc7+ Ke6 32. Nd4+ Kd6 33. Rxe5 fxe5 34. Rh7 Rxb2+ 35. Ke1 exd4 36. Rxh6+ Ke5 37. fxg4 Rxa2 38. g5 $11}

\mainline[level=1]{ 30... Rb6 $15 31. b3 Rxh5 32. Rh1 Rxh1 33. Rxh1 Kg6 34. Ne2 Ra6 35. a4 Rb6 36. Nf4+ Kg7 37. Nh5+ Kh7 38. Rc1 Rxb3 $2 }

\variation[level=2]{38... gxf3 39. Rb1 Rc6 40. Kxf3 Rc3+ 41. Ke2 f5 $15}

\mainline[level=1]{ 39. Nxf6+ Kg6 40. Nxd5 $2 $138 }

\variation[level=2]{40. Nxg4 Nf5 $1 41. Rc5 }\\(    \variation[level=3]{41. Kg2 $11})\\
\variation[level=2]{ 41... Rb2+ 42. Ke1 Nxg3 43. Rxd5 $11}

\begin{samepage}    \mainline[level=1]{ 40... Rxf3+ $19 41. Kg2 Nf5 42. Nf4+ Kf6 43. Ne2 b6 44. Rc7 Ne3+ 45. Kh1 Rf1+ 46. Ng1 Rf2 47. Rc6+ Kg5 } \rbwins\end{samepage}
```

Now, I want the PGN4LaTeX3 to output with this manner in my books' code (you might change the name of counter):

```
\makeatletter
\newcounter{answers}
\extrarowheight3pt
\newlength\colwidth
\renewcommand*\makegametitle{\par\bigskip\newgame  
    \refstepcounter{answers}%
    \settowidth\colwidth{\fontsize{8mm}{1cm}\bfseries \theanswers}
    \noindent\begin{tabular}{|p{\colwidth}|p{\dimexpr\linewidth-\colwidth-3\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}@{}}
    \hline
&
    \strut$\Box$\quad\textbf{\wname}\ \@welo\hfill\\
    \raisebox{0\ht\strutbox}[0pt][0pt]{\fontsize{8mm}{1cm}\bfseries \theanswers}
    &\strut$\blacksquare$\quad\textbf{\bname}\ \@belo\hfill\\
    &\strut\quad\@tourn\hfill\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}\par\nopagebreak\bigskip\nopagebreak}
```

How can I change the code of original PGN4LaTeX3 (I don't want to share the code due to copyrights) that it might create the header in the way above?

Comment: Sorry but asking to adapt a quite complex python script to a quite vage spec is out of scope of this site - both in topic than in time.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer No, I adapted. I've meant how should I redact PGN4LaTeX3.tex file, which is in the scope of the site.

Answer (score 0):

I tried, and eventually, managed to create a code satisfying me in pgn2latex3.tex file (You might keep the pgn2latex_out file without changes):

```
\documentclass[%
    paper=letter,                   % paper size --> A4 is default in Germany
    twoside=true,               % onesite or twoside printing
    %openright,                 % doublepage cleaning ends up right side
    parskip=half,               % spacing value / method for paragraphs
    chapterprefix=true,         % prefix for chapter marks
    10pt,                       % font size
    headings=normal,            % size of headings
    bibliography=totoc,         % include bib in toc
    listof=totoc,               % include listof entries in toc
    titlepage=on,               % own page for each title page
    captions=tableabove,        % display table captions above the float env
    draft=false,                % value for draft version
    twocolumn=false,%
]{scrbook}%
\setlength\columnsep{0.6cm}
\usepackage[
  top=1.3cm,bottom=1.8cm,left=1.85cm,right=1.7cm,%1cm is lost in the middle for each doublepage, right should be 2*(left-1cm) left 2.33cm, right 2.67cm works, 2cm both, too.
  %margin=2.5cm,% each margin should be 2cm
  includeheadfoot,% text area includes header
  nofoot,% no space for footer
  %showframe% show the page layout
]{geometry}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{luatex85}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets pagestyle scrheadings automatically
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\pagemark}
\chead{\headmark}
%Kopfzeile nicht kursiv
\renewcommand*{\headfont}{\normalfont}


\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
%short, stretchable space
\newcommand\shortspace{\ \hspace{-0.167em}}
\xskaknewstyleitem[%
template=UF,
whiteopen=.\shortspace,
blackopen=\ldots\shortspace]{styleN}


\xskaknewstyle[level= 1,styleitem=styleN,font=\bfseries,
               level= 2,styleitem=styleN,
               level= 3,styleitem=styleN,font=\itshape,
               level= 4,styleitem=styleN,
               level= 5,styleitem=styleN]{FK}

\xskakset{style=FK}
\renewcommand\castlinghyphen{\mbox{-}}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength\columnsep{1cm}
\multicoltolerance = 9999
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[title=Games,columns=1]
\makeindex[name=players,title=Players,columns=3]
\makeindex[name=positions,title=Positions,columns=1]


\newcommand\resetPgnTags{%
  \def\WhitePlayer{}%
  \def\BlackPlayer{}%
  \def\WhiteElo{}%
  \def\BlackElo{}%
  \def\Result{}%
  \def\Site{}%
  \def\Event{}%
  \def\Round{}%
  \def\Date{}%
  \def\Eco{}}

\usepackage{nicefrac}

\newcommand{\arabicz}[1]{\ifnum\value{#1}<100 0\fi\ifnum\value{#1}<10 0\fi\arabic{#1}}
\newcommand\whiteWins{\mbox{1 -- 0}}
\newcommand\blackWins{\mbox{0 -- 1}}
\newcommand\aDraw{\mbox{\nicefrac{1}{2} -- \nicefrac{1}{2}}}
\newcommand\unclearResult{}%was $\ast$
\newcommand\worseis{\scalebox{1.333}[1.273]{$\blacktriangle$}} %ChessBase uses \leq, this is from ChessAssistant
\newcommand\equalis{$=$}
\newcounter{gameNr}
\setcounter{gameNr}{0}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newcommand\gameHeader{%
\makeatletter
\extrarowheight3pt
\par\bigskip
    \refstepcounter{gameNr}%
    \settowidth\columnwidth{\fontsize{1cm}{1cm}\bfseries \thegameNr}
    \noindent\begin{tabular}{|p{\columnwidth}|p{\dimexpr\linewidth-\columnwidth-3\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}@{}|}
    \hline
    &
    \strut$\square$\quad\textbf{\WhitePlayer{}}\ \WhiteElo{}\hfill\\
    \raisebox{-1.5\ht\strutbox}[0pt][0pt]{\fontsize{1cm}{1cm}\bfseries \thegameNr}
    &
    \strut
    \ifx\BlackPlayer\empty{}\hfill\\
    \else
    $\blacksquare$\quad\textbf{\BlackPlayer{}}\ \BlackElo{}\hfill\\
    \fi
    &
    \ifx
    \Event{}\empty{}
    \else
    \par\strut\quad\textit{\Event{}}\hfill\\
    \fi
    &
    \ifx
    \Site{}\empty{}
    \else
    \par\strut\quad\textit{\Site{}} \ \Round{}\hfill\\
    \fi
    \hline
    \end{tabular}\par\nopagebreak\bigskip\nopagebreak}



%
%% INDEXING %%%
\ifx\BlackPlayer\empty{}%@\textit{\Event{}}: \WhitePlayer{} (Nr. \arabic{gameNr}%
    \index[positions]{\Event{}: \WhitePlayer{}|textbf}\else%
    \index{\WhitePlayer{}\BlackPlayer{}\arabicz{gameNr}@\textsc{\WhitePlayer{}} -- \textsc{\BlackPlayer{}}\ \relax%
    \ifx\Event\Date{}%
    \else%
    \textit{\Event{}} \textbf{\Date{}}%
        \if\Round Rd.\Round{}%
        \fi%
    \fi%
\ (Nr. \arabic{gameNr})|textbf}%
    \fi%
\ifx\BlackPlayer\empty{}%
\else%
\index[players]{\WhitePlayer{}|textbf}%
\index[players]{\BlackPlayer{}|textbf}%
\fi%
\message{Processing game Nr. \arabic{gameNr}}%


\newcommand\merke[2][]{
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=\textsf{Regel},arc=0mm,boxrule=0.7pt,center title,colback=orange!5,colframe=orange!93!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,titlerule=0pt,#1]%
#2%
\end{tcolorbox}
}

\newcommand\rwwins{\nopagebreak[4]{\par\centering\textbf{\whiteWins}\par\medskip}}
\newcommand\rbwins{\nopagebreak[4]{\par\centering\textbf{\blackWins}\par\medskip}}
\newcommand\rdraw{\nopagebreak[4]{\par\centering\textbf{\aDraw}\par\medskip}}
\newcommand\runclea{}%{\par\centering\textbf{\unclearResult}\par}}

\frenchspacing

\newcommand\dia{{\,(D)}}
\newcommand\diav{\,(D)}
\newcommand\takes{\capturesymbol}
\newcommand\sn{\symknight}
\newcommand\sk{\symking}
\renewcommand\sb{\symbishop}
\newcommand\sr{\symrook}
\newcommand\sq{\symqueen}
\renewcommand\sp{\sympawn}

\renewcommand\chessdiagramname{\ (D)}

%\newcommand{\chessboards}[1]{\chessboard[pgfstyle=border,padding=0.3ex,linewidth=0.1ex,backregion=h8-a1,#1]}
\newcommand{\chessboards}[1]{\chessboardn[#1]} %no special boards
\newcommand{\chessboardn}[1][]{\chessboard[labelfontsize=10pt,boardfontsize=16.3pt,label=false,marginleft=false,margintopwidth=\baselineskip-11pt,marginbottom=false,#1]\vspace{5pt}}
\newcommand{\chessboardt}[1][]{\chessboard[labelfontsize=9pt,boardfontsize=14pt,label=false,marginleft=false,margintopwidth=\baselineskip-10pt,marginbottom=false,#1]\vspace{5pt}}

\hyphenation{Shake-speare}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=false,
    linktoc=all
}

%%%setting up the Merida chess font
\pdfmapfile{=chess-enpassant.map}
\setchessboard{
    boardfontfamily=merida,
}
\setfigfontfamily{merida}
%%%

\newcommand{\intro}[1]{
\end{multicols}%
\begin{multicols}{2}%
#1
\end{multicols}%
\vspace{\baselineskip}
\needspace{20\baselineskip}%
\begin{multicols}{3}%
}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{multicol}

\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{%
  \vspace*{0\baselineskip}%
}%

\renewcommand*{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
  \hspace*{#2}%
  \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-#2\relax}{\raggedsection
    \ifstr{#3}{}{}{#3\\}%
    #4}%
}
%quotation marks according to the current language
\newcommand{\qqstart}{``{}}
\newcommand{\qqend}{''{}}

\begin{document}
%\cleardoublepage

%\tableofcontents
%\cleardoublepage

\begin{multicols}{2}
%\chapter{}
%This is a chapter created by pgn2latex.
\include{pgn2latex_out}

\end{multicols}

%\cleardoublepage
%\printindex
%\printindex[players]
%\printindex[positions]

\end{document}
```